# Does the adsense bot ever get bored?

Tags: google-adsense, web-crawlers

Each time someone clicks on a page like

```
http://www.example.com/crazy.cgi?input=silly+banana
```

where the "silly banana" bit represents some arbitrary user input which changes each time, I get yet another hit from the Adsense bot, almost immediately afterwards. And yet the page's contents don't vary much depending on the input. Is there a point at which the Adsense bot (user agent "Mediapartners-Google") gets bored, in other words begins to notice that the query parameters don't make much difference to the output page, or does it just keep on and on coming to my page indefinitely? And if there is a point where its enthusiasm begins to wane, can it be predicted?

Answer (score 1):

Along with data on your website, AdSense also usually indexes/checks the cookie listing the topics of sites your visitors have been to, so even with the changing queries, Google still can fallback to the statistics from the network and your visitors to make an educated guess as to what should be shown.

The PSA ads typically come up unintentionally when Google has yet to index your page for the first time or when it doesn't have at least a (very) lowball estimate for ads.

Answer (score 0):

Google AdSense needs to know the content of your page to display the most relevant ads. In your case, it's likely the Mediapartner bot will continue to fetch the page each time a new query is entered. This is because your query doesn't fall into a common "ignore" pattern, such as pages with `sid` parameter.

If you don't want Mediapartner bot to access your page, you can disallow it in your `robots.txt`.

Comment: If I disallow the bot it will serve public service ads.